# make file appear readonly to a library function

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

I'm using a library that can read or write some metadata that I need from files.

I only need to read and I know that my files are on slow storage.

I noticed that while reading the values I need is very fast, closing the files is slow. Basically, if I `open(); read(); close()` each file my program is quite slow, but if I only `open(); read()` during operation and `close()` right before exit (i.e. I let my run-time close the files during finalization of the leaked objects) the program runs fast, but stops for several seconds just before exit - when the files are being closed.

On the other hand, if I remove write permission from the files this doesn't happen: it seems that files open readonly are closed much faster than the files open read-write. It could be that the library writes metadata on close "just to be sure" if the file is writable, or some other reason, but anyway - it's impossible to specify for the library that I wan't to open the file only for reading: it tries to be intelligent and decides based on file permissions.

At the moment to speed things up I'm changing file permissions just before opening it and restoring permissions after the metadata is read. It works, but it feels wrong.

Is there a way in linux / unix to make files appear readonly to the current process temporarily? I can't use setuid(2) because the program is ran by unpriviledged user (or am I wrong about this?).

**details**

The library is [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) which is in turn a wrapper around [taglib](http://taglib.github.io/)'s C++ API.

The program may list the tracks on the device and needs to know their length in seconds (the reason I use taglib), but the same media will be written to (new tracks uploaded, some tracks deleted) hence I can't just force users to mount the device readonly.

I realize that a better solution would be patching taglib to allow to specify that I just want to read the metadata, then patch taglib-ruby to wrap the new API. But I'm not up to it, plus I have a workaround already, thus not much insetive to go down that route. I'm just wondering if there is a better workaround.

Comment: Is it the library that calls the `open()` function, or is it you opening the file and passing a `FILE *` as argument to functions from the library?

Comment: remount the directory using "-bind,ro" switch. And ask taglib to operate on read-only filesystem. It should stop library from opening file in write mode.( not sure if -bind switch is supported on all distributions )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  You access the file and then the `atime` is updated on a `close()`.  This causes a `write()` to the file system.  Also: [relatime](http://kerneltrap.org/node/14148).  At the very least, you can rule out `atime` by a mount with **noatime**.  Mounting with **ro** will have the same effect as per [Icarus3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1919896/icarus3).  I guess the library maybe re-writing something; is the modified time updated?  At least that could provide helpful information.

Comment: As well `strace -e trace=open,write,close` might be helpful.  You will get a brief overview of what is being written, if that is the case.

Comment: IOStream * stream = new FileStream ("/path/to/file", true);//true means open in read mode only
File * file = new File( stream ); //constructor is protected, so extend File class
FileRef fileref( file ); //now use fileref...

Comment: @Rubens It's the library that actually opens/reads/closes the files, I pass a file name to the library and the library provides no way to specify that I'm only gonna be reading.

Comment: @Icarus3 I need the storage be writable, I only want it to "appear readonly" to taglib. the user of the program might be copying files to the same storage, deleting the files etc. I just don't want the metadata reading slow everything down.

Comment: I added some more explanations.

Comment: oh, and it isn't atime because my media is FAT (an ipod shuffle mounted as mass storage device).

Comment: Oh, @Icarus3, your second suggestion seems like a solution (passing open file to the taglib File/FileRef). I'll have a look at extending taglib-ruby to allow that. Thanks. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you could do something like this: ( I hope you could do it in ruby too )

```
TagLib::IOStream * stream = new TagLib::FileStream("blow.mp4", true);

TagLib::MP4::File * file = new TagLib::MP4::File( stream );

TagLib::FileRef * fileref =  new TagLib::FileRef( file );

TagLib::String artist = fileref->tag()->artist();
```

Here, second argument to FileStream's constructor represents read-only.
I have confirmed using "strace" that open system calls are invoked with O_RDONLY

Comment: I can't use it in ruby right away, but I've proposed the ruby wrapper author to make this possible. If push comes to shove I'm prepared to add this myself if only to learn ruby C API.